# Oracle Apex. Is it possible to Ignore Process on Error?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Is it possible to ignore a process if that process does not work?  
I have a process that sends an email when the user clicks the Create button on my page.  But the problem is that I can send up to 50 emails per day for security reasons.  If the user exceeds 50 emails, this process displays an error and stops.  So I can not save the new record.  Is it possible on error to ignore this process and continue to save the new record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an exception  "when others" that will ignore any error

for example

```
declare
    l_id number;
begin
l_id := apex_mail.send(
    p_to        => 'fred@flintstone.com',
    p_from      => 'barney@rubble.com',
    p_subj      => 'APEX_MAIL with attachment',
    p_body      => 'Please review the attachment.',
    p_body_html => '<b>Please</b> review the attachment');

for c1 in (select filename, blob_content, mime_type 
    from apex_application_files
    where id in (123,456)) loop

    apex_mail.add_attachment(
        p_mail_id    => l_id,
        p_attachment => c1.blob_content,
        p_filename   => c1.filename,
        p_mime_type  => c1.mime_type);
    end loop;
commit;

exception
    when others 
    then
        rollback;
        null;
end;
```

Comment: Hi @Valèrio and thank you for your response. This is not a procedure but a process that APEX has to send an email automatically

Comment: But you can create a process using the APEX_MAIL package and control the errors

Comment: edited the answer with an example, hope it helps

Comment: You are right! It works perfectly! Thank you very much!!